# How do you use a JavaScript function from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

So I have a file:

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
function rateLimiter(request, ms) {}
function startServer(port, dir) {}
```

And i want to call those two functions in another file

index.js

```
const express = require("server.js");
var rate = rateLimiter(100, 60000);
var server = startServer(8080, src);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to export those functions and then import them where you need them

Answer (score 0):

write something like:

module.exports = {rateLimiter, startServer}

Answer (score 0):

You need to exports those functions and import them to other files.

Here is the export

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
function rateLimiter(request, ms) {}
function startServer(port, dir) {}

module.exports = {rateLimiter, startServer}
```

And here is the import

index.js

```
const express = require("server.js");
const {rateLimiter, startServer} = require('./server.js'); // your server.js file
var rate = rateLimiter(100, 60000);
var server = startServer(8080, src);
```